# Create Product Publish to Multiple Channels

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to determine if the bigcommerce API allows you to create a new product and have it display in multiple channels not just the web store. The API documentation doesn't seem to mention anything about channel management for products, is this possible?

Comment: The BigCommerce API publishes products to a BigCommerce store. It'd probably make more sense to use an API for an individual channel to be able to publish products to it.

Answer (score 0):

Channel management configuration and publishing isn't currently available in the BigCommerce API